# warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository - GitHubCLI

Tags: linux, git, script, github

Estoy haciendo un script en linux para automatizar la creación de repositorios para mi grupo de trabajo.
Lo que quiero hacer es crear un repositorio en Github basado en un témplate, clonarlo en una ubicación especifica, pero muchas veces me indica `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository` y otras pocas veces no arroja ese error... No se como solucionarlo

En la linea donde creo el repositorio

`gh repo create $1 --private -p https://github.com/user/template` también le paso la bandera `--clone`, pero obtengo el mismo resultado y me agrega el siguente error: `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/main`, aclaro porque en el script utilizo `gh repo clone`

Para ejecutarlo corro lo siguiente `sudo bash script.sh <proyecto>`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# -*- ENCODING: UTF-8 -*-

set -u
echo token > .token
gh auth login --with-token < .token
rm .token

gh repo create $1 --private -p https://github.com/user/template

gh repo clone https://github.com/user/$1 /var/www/$1

cd /var/www/$1 && composer update --no-interaction

gh auth logout

exit
```

Note algo importante, si yo creo el repositorio basado en el template desde la plataforma de github, lleva un tiempo en procesar, pero con el comando `gh` lo creo y luego lo clona, entonces sospecho que lo clona antes de terminar el proceso

Comment: No creo que el problema sea algo del lado del cliente.... estás seguro de que los repositorios que estás tratando de clonar tienen contenido? Pareciera que no. Verifica alguno de los repositorios donde te da el error al tratar de clonar.

Comment: Si, los repositorios tienen contenido, es mas si yo entro a la carpeta y hago git pull me trae los archivos,

Comment: Agregue una observación al final de la pregunta que me parecio muy importante